# Export SQL Server data from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a SQL server database of a web application, my requirement is to read 2-3 table data from one source database and insert the data in the destination database. My input will be a Name and an ID, based on that I have to read data from the source database and I have to validate whether the similar Name already exists in the destination database. I have to do this via a C# windows application or a web application.

So far in my research, people have recommended using SqlBulkCopy or an SSIS package, I tried to transfer one table data using the following code.

```
        using (SqlConnection connSource = new SqlConnection(csSource))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = connSource.CreateCommand())
        using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(csDest))
        {
            bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable";
            cmd.CommandText = "myproc";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connSource.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }
```

The problem I'm facing is that, I have to copy 2 table data, based on table 1, table 2 value like ID(primary key) changes, I have to update this in the SqlDataReader, so in order to get this new ID in the destination database, I have to insert one table data first, then get the ID, then update this ID in my reader object and then do another SqlBulkCopy, this doesn't look like the ideal way to do this, is there any other to do this?

Comment: Could you specify if both database are on the same SQL instance ?

Comment: No not in the same instance

Answer (score 0):

On the source SQL instance I would create a linked server referencing destination/target SQL instance and then I would create a stored procedure within source database thus:

```
USE SourceDatabase
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ExportSomething
@param1 DataType1,
@param2 DataType2, ...
AS
BEGIN

INSERT LinkedServer.DestinationDatabase.dbo.TargetTable
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.Table1 INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 ....
WHERE Col1 = @param1 AND/OR ...

END
GO
```

Then, the final step is to call this stored procedure from client application.

Comment: My requirement is that I'd be getting the destination SQL Server Connection details from the user, the database name could be anything, so I found that I can use sp_addlinkedserver to programmatically create a linked server, so in your answer is it possible for me to dynamically change LinkedServer.DestinationDatabase part based on user input?

Comment: You could create a linked static like this /*using sp_add*/ only if this stored procedure could be executed by a single used once. If two users will execute this stored procedure *in the same time* then this solution isn't optimal. Instead, you could use OPENDATASOURCE() function ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql)) within with dinamic sql (ODS function doesn't accept variables - ex. @connection_string - as paramters).